# Unsetting environment variables Classic Azure Pipeline steps

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

We're using snapcraft snaps to publish our software. We have a classic pipeline step for logging into snapcraft, one for releasing the snap and one for logging out. However, we're unable to release the snap because the agent loses the context between logging in and releasing and thus can't release the snap.

1st step:
`export SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS=$(cat $(Agent.TempDirectory)/[OUR-EXPORTED-LOGIN])`

2nd step:
`snapcraft release [SNAPNAME] "$(Revision)" "candidate"`

3rd step:
`unset SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS`

So in the second step we're getting:

```
Starting Snapcraft 7.5.2
craft-store error: No keyring found to store or retrieve credentials from.
Ensure the keyring is working or SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS is correctly exported into the environment
For more information, check out: https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapcraft-authentication
```

If we instead place the contents of step 2 inside step 1 the command works as intended. This indicates to us that SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS is unset between the steps. This is strange because ordinarily this only happens between jobs and not steps.

Answer (score 1):

Because you only export `SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS` in your first steps, so the visibility of this variable is task level.

You can [set a job-scoped variable from a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&amp%3Btabs=yaml%2Cbatch&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script-1). To set a variable from a script, use the `task.setvariable` logging command. This doesn't update the environment variables, but it does make the new variable available to downstream steps within the same job.

For example, add this command in your first step if you are using a Command line task:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS]$(SNAPCRAFT_STORE_CREDENTIALS)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I solved this by logging in and releasing in the same step. I checked with my boss and we both thought the legacy code wasn't best practice. We also had the tasks in a task group, so it was really easy to change.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested that you accept your answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).